# pqxx::connection with or without pointer

Tags: c++, libpqxx

I am working with the PostgreSql library http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx and my question is if to create a connection it is better to create a pointer or on the contrary let the library manage the memory.
That is, pqxx :: connection c {"postgresql: // accounting @ localhost / company"};
Versus mycon= new pqxx :: connection c {"postgresql: // accounting @ localhost / company"};
And in general if it is a good programming practice in c ++ to encapsulate the library in other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You never want a pointer if a local object will do. That's a general rule of C++, and it applies to pqxx just the same.

As for encapsulating it, that seems like a lot of work, but to what end? If you want to abstract your data layer, do so on an abstraction level that makes sense for your application, not on the level of "which library do I use to access PostgreSQL?"

Comment: I'm using http://www.pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/. I am a senior programmer and I agree with you, but convincing juniors is difficult and I like to contrast my opinions